# Visual Studio 2017 adding unwanted dll's after publishing

Tags: c#, razor, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-2017

I have a web application built using .NET Framework 4.5.1

When i publish it from VS2017, VS2017 adds unwanted dll's, not listed in the references, which are :

`System.Web.Mvc.dll`
`System.Web.Razor.dll`
`System.Web.Webpages.Deployment.dll`
`System.Web.Webpages.Razor.dll`

When i try to publish from VS2013 it gives runtime error (razor missing) and my project doesn't have any cshtml file and of course it's not using any razor views.

Why does VS2013 require razor and is there any way to stop VS2017 adding razor and other unwanted dll's when  publishing?

Thank you!!

**EDIT: ** From researching, i found that adding `<PreserveCompilationContext>false</PreserveCompilationContext>` in my csproj file, would stop VS2017 from adding razor, but after publishing now i get runtime error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried examining the Options under the Debug menu in Visual Studio, one of the settings allows you to control this (under package/publish) by choosing Items to deploy: Only Files Needed to Run This Application

It is also possible that one of the assemblies you are referencing is required by another assembly.

[snapshot of the configuration window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFVig.png)

Comment: Is there a packages.config file in the solution explorer, or perhaps check Manage NuGet Packages under Project

Comment: Yes there is a packages.config file in the solution explorer and i don't have there MVC package or Razor package. I understood that maybe it's `System.Web.Mvc.dll` asking for razor. And also `System.Web.Mvc.dll` is added by VS2017. So maybe one of my assembiles is referencing `System.Web.Mvc.dll` and i am stuck in figuring out which one..